# SQL Query from two tables with intersection and union but also with other unique properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables

Table 1

```
Brand  | Price| Shape |weight  |Color |URL
--------------------------------
Philips| 13   | Square| 12lbs  |Blue  |example.com/123
Philips| 4    | Round | 17 lbs |Yellow|example.com/1567
```

Table 2

```
Brand  | Price| Shape  |weight |Color |URL
--------------------------------
Philips| 12   | Square | 12lbs |Blue  |example.com/456
Philips| 4    | Round  | 16 lbs|Yellow|example.com/17987
GE     | 4    | Square | 17 lbs|red   |example.com/17234234
```

I want to write SQL queries where I can select the product from both these tables by comparing the cheapest price, all the properties and the URL. I tried with join

```
select  
    case when a.price < b.price then A.price else B.price end as price,
    * 
from 
    Table1 A, table2 B   
where
    A.Brand = B.Brand 
    and A.Shape = B.Shape 
    and A.weight = B.weight 
    and A.color = B.color
```

But this returns duplicate results.

I tried with union and intersection but then it does not give me URL

```
SELECT  
    Brand , Shape, weight, color, URL 
FROM 
    table1 
WHERE
    Price !='NULL' 
    AND BulbShape != 'null' 
    AND Wattage != 'null' 
    AND Lumens_Initial != 'null' 

UNION

SELECT 
    Brand, Shape, weight, color, URL 
FROM 
    table2  
WHERE 
    Price != 'NULL' 
    AND Shape != 'null' 
    AND weight != 'null' 
    AND color != 'null'

EXCEPT 

SELECT 
    Brand, Shape, weight, color, URL   
FROM 
    table1 
WHERE 
    Price != 'NULL' 
    AND Shape != 'null' 
    AND weight != 'null' 
    AND color != 'null'

INTERSECT 

SELECT 
    Brand, Shape, weight, color, URL 
FROM 
    table2 
WHERE
    Price != 'NULL' 
    AND Shape != 'null' 
    AND Wattage != 'null' 
    AND color != 'null'
```

I don't have any primary key since its just collected data from web.

How can I write a query to fetch the data which is unique, include all the columns and min price from both the table?

Expected result should be something like

```
Brand  | Price| Shape  |weight  |Color  |URL
--------------------------------------------------------------
Philips| 12   | Square | 12 lbs |Blue   |example.com/123
Philips| 4    | Round  | 17 lbs |Yellow |example.com/1567
Philips| 4    | Round  | 16 lbs |Yellow |example.com/17987
GE     | 4    | Square | 17 lbs |red    |example.com/17234234
```

In the first row I just got the min price rest remain the same from the first table. Second row have different properties so I got rows from both the table. Last the row is only there in second table so i got that row.

Comment: Can you format your tables and queries to make it easier to read? Also, which database are you using?  Did you tag MySQL by mistake?

Comment: What are your expected results with that sample data?

Comment: Are you asking about [`UNION ALL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) ?

Comment: No I am asking how to compare two table for a particular column and get the other column value as well.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: *I don't have any primary key* .... ***ANY*** table in your system (with the possible exception of temporay / staging tables) ***always*** ought to have a primary key! It's what allows you to reliably identify a single row in a table. You ***NEED*** a primary key - on every table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE Procedure joindemo
 as

CREATE TABLE #table1
(
    brand varchar(50),
    price int,
    shape varchar(50),
    weight varchar(50),
    color varchar(50),
    url varchar(100)
    )

CREATE TABLE #table2
(
    brand varchar(50),
    price int,
    shape varchar(50),
    weight varchar(50),
    color varchar(50),
    url varchar(100)
    )


INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES('Philips', 13, 'Square', '12lbs', 'Blue', 'example.com/123')
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES('Philips', 4, 'Round', '17lbs', 'Yellow', 'example.com/1567')
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('Philips', 12, 'Square', '12lbs', 'Blue', 'example.com/456')
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('Philips', 4, 'Round', '16lbs', 'Yellow', 'example.com/17987')
INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES('GE', 4, 'Square', '17lbs', 'Red', 'example.com/17234234')

CREATE TABLE #jointable
(
    brand varchar(50),
    price int,
    shape varchar(50),
    weight varchar(50),
    color varchar(50),
    url varchar(100)
    )

INSERT INTO #jointable 
SELECT * FROM #table1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM #table2

SELECT 
j.brand, mp.minprice, j.shape, j.weight, j.color, j.url FROM
(SELECT brand, Min(price) as minprice, shape, weight, color  FROM
#jointable
GROUP BY brand, shape, weight, color) as mp
INNER JOIN #jointable j ON mp.brand = j.brand AND mp.minprice = j.price
AND mp.color = j.color AND mp.shape = j.shape and mp.weight = j.weight

DROP TABLE #table1
DROP TABLE #table2
DROP TABLE #jointable

--exec joindemo;
```

Please note that your expected output is wrong.  The url in the first line should be example.com/456.  Also you will need to decide what to do, if you get two prices the same!  Because you did not specify, I couldn't second guess if you wanted to show two or just one!

Answer (score 1):

It's a classic `top-n-per-group`.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
    brand varchar(50),
    price int,
    shape varchar(50),
    weight varchar(50),
    color varchar(50),
    url varchar(100)
);

DECLARE @table2 TABLE
(
    brand varchar(50),
    price int,
    shape varchar(50),
    weight varchar(50),
    color varchar(50),
    url varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO @table1 (brand,price,shape,weight,color,url) VALUES
('Philips', 13, 'Square', '12lbs', 'Blue', 'example.com/123'),
('Philips', 4, 'Round', '17lbs', 'Yellow', 'example.com/1567');

INSERT INTO @table2 (brand,price,shape,weight,color,url) VALUES
('Philips', 12, 'Square', '12lbs', 'Blue', 'example.com/456'),
('Philips', 4, 'Round', '16lbs', 'Yellow', 'example.com/17987'),
('GE', 4, 'Square', '17lbs', 'Red', 'example.com/17234234');
```

**Query**

At first `UNION ALL` two tables into `CTE_Tables`. Then use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate numbers for each row partitioned by all the properties and ordered by price (`CTE_RN`). Finally select only first row for each group.

```
WITH
CTE_Tables
AS
(
    SELECT brand,price,shape,weight,color,url
    FROM @table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT brand,price,shape,weight,color,url
    FROM @table2
)
,CTE_RN
AS
(
    SELECT brand,price,shape,weight,color,url
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY brand,shape,weight,color
            ORDER BY price) AS rn
    FROM CTE_Tables
)
SELECT brand,price,shape,weight,color,url
FROM CTE_RN
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY brand DESC,price DESC,shape DESC,weight DESC,color,url;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+----------------------+
|  brand  | price | shape  | weight | color  |         url          |
+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+----------------------+
| Philips |    12 | Square | 12lbs  | Blue   | example.com/456      |
| Philips |     4 | Round  | 17lbs  | Yellow | example.com/1567     |
| Philips |     4 | Round  | 16lbs  | Yellow | example.com/17987    |
| GE      |     4 | Square | 17lbs  | Red    | example.com/17234234 |
+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+----------------------+
```